# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing etree: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, lxml, importerror, docx, elementtree

I am trying to import and use the docx module but it gives me the following error:

```
>>> from docx import Document
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\docx\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from docx.api import Document  # noqa
  File ".\docx\api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from docx.package import Package
  File ".\docx\package.py", line 9, in <module>
    from docx.opc.package import OpcPackage
  File ".\docx\opc\package.py", line 9, in <module>
    from docx.opc.part import PartFactory
  File ".\docx\opc\part.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .oxml import serialize_part_xml
  File ".\docx\opc\oxml.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing etree: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I am not sure what the problem is because it was working fine before, but suddenly it has started giving this error. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling lxml, but it didn't change anything. I then uninstalled and reinstalled docx and it gives me this (very similar) error instead:

```
from docx import Document
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\docx.py", line 17, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing etree: The parameter is incorrect.
```

if I try 'pip show lxml' this is the result:

```
C:\Users\Radha Muthuswamy>pip show lxml
Name: lxml
Version: 4.5.2
Summary: Powerful and Pythonic XML processing library combining libxml2/libxslt with the ElementTree API.
Home-page: https://lxml.de/
Author: lxml dev team
Author-email: lxml-dev@lxml.de
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\radha muthuswamy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: docx
```

I need this software working soon, so please any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What happens when you just import etree from lxml? I.e., `from lxml import etree`

Comment: It gives me the same error unfortunately. If I do just `import lxml`, it is fine,but if I do `from lxml import etree`, it gives me that error.

Comment: What does `pip show lxml` print to the console?

Comment: I edited the question to show the result you wanted

Comment: I have the exact same version and I get no errors here. Any errors when you do an uninstall then an install of lxml using pip?

Comment: no it is fine. is it the python version maybe? I use 3.8.5

Comment: I too am at 3.8.5. Seeing as you're on Windows, have you rebooted?

Comment: yeah I have :-(

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? If so, then make sure you call pip with the correct version. E.g., on my Windows 10 machine, I'd launch pip via `py -3.8-64 -m pip show lxml`

Comment: no, I only have one python version installed, 3.8.5, and I did the uninstalling and reinstalling of lxml (and docx) using pip on that version